# Is it possible to make a scrollbar?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

How to make a scrollbar in the tabs in the 3D view sidebar using python ?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. But take a look on this add-on:

https://gumroad.com/l/simpletabs

https://blendermarket.com/products/simple-tabs

It can reorder tabs and group several tabs into one. So you can save a lot of space putting several add-ons (that you don't often use) into one tab, or group add-ons by functionality.